# How to get the last previous object from a NSMutableArray in iOs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

```
NSMutableArray * Cars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"Audi", @"BMW",
                          @"Audi Quattro", @"Audi", nil];
```

How to get the last previous object from a NSMutableArray? 
Also each time when i add a new object, i want to fetch the last previous object in the NSMutableArray. Can any one please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the last object:

```
id lastObject = array.lastObject;
```

For the second to last object:

```
id previousLastObject = array.lastObject;
[array addObject:newObject];
```

Or

```
[array addObject:newObject];
id previousLastObject = array[array.count - 2];
```

Comment: It also doesn't need one, assuming it's known that there is a second to last object.  The answers are supposed to show technique, not be production-quality code.

Comment: Fine; "Your last code sample assumes the array has at least two objects."

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *car=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

car = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Audi", @"BMW",@"Audi Quattro", @"Audi", nil];

int count=(int)[car count];

NSLog(@"Object at second last index %@",[car objectAtIndex:count-2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think using category makes sense.

In NSArray category, you can declare a method like:

```
@implementation NSArray (Utils)

- (id)getNextToLastObject {
    if (self.count < 2) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [self objectAtIndex: self.count - 2];
    }
}
@end
```

Then it can be called for any array in the project like:

```
Model *model = [modelArray getNextToLastObject];
```

ps: You should import your category class's header file to your controller.